# Connection timeout to Couchbase using jdbc

Tags: jdbc, couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I am trying to connect to Couchbase through JDBC, but it is behaving arbitrarily as it gives a timeout exception many times. I also tried to increase the time out, but it still errors out. The following is the code used to connect to Couchbase:

```
public static CouchbaseCluster connectToDB(String URL, String userid, String password) throws BusinessException
        {
            CouchbaseEnvironment env = null;
            CouchbaseCluster cluster = null;
            try 
            {
                env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder().connectTimeout(10000).queryEnabled(true).build();
                cluster = CouchbaseCluster.fromConnectionString(env, URL);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
            }
            return cluster;
        }
```

Also, we are using Jars :couchbase-core-io-1.2.7.jar and couchbase-java-client-2.2.6 and the couchbase version we are trying to connect to is Couchbase version 4.5.1-2841 Enterprise Edition

I also tried to increase the timeout using .connectTimeout(1000000), but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that all ports are open in between the client and the server?  The ports are listed here

http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/install/install-ports.html